# How to integrate AdMob as a backup for iAds?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob, iad

```
import iAd 
@IBOutlet weak var Banner: ADBannerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    Banner.hidden = true   
    Banner.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true 
}
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.Banner.hidden = false
}
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error:   NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error")

}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
}
```

Hello,
I am currently developing an iOS app with Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.0, and iOS 9.2. I have implemented iAds, and it works perfectly. However in my region the fill rate is not high, and I would like to use Google's AdMob to advertise on my app, as a backup. I would like for the AdMob banner ad to show up when iAd does not receive an ad. Note that I am new to Swift, and have no knowledge of Objective-C. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the AdMob ad (and view) in the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`. supposing that this callback will be called when no iAd is available (I think so).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will test this soon when I get time, and will get back to you soon.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Works beautifully. Implemented it in my app, [Blue Saber](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blue-saber-the-lightsaber-app/id1076077872?l=en&mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

You idea is, you are going to support two add platforms.

In this case, suppose you are trying to load adMob first.
If adMob will fails, simply load iAD.

Similarly if iAD will fail, load adMob.

**So in `didFail` delegate method of adMob, write code to load iAD.**

**In `didFail` delegate method of iAD, write code to load adMob.**

this way you can get your required result.